# Google Analytics - Visitor-Level custom variables. Once and done?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to start assigning each member that logs into my website with a unique ID (saved as a visitor-level custom variable). If I save a visitor-level custom variable when the user logs in, is that value with them for the life of the cookie? The end goal would be to see the trends of all logged in users and then break that trend down to an individual user level. I want to make sure I don't need to track that generated unique ID I'm on each page in order to see information per ID, though. If my understanding of custom variable scopes are correct, I should not have to.

If this is the case, then, how do I handle multiple users per PC? If I overwrite that visitor-level variable on each successful login, will results be screwy when looking at the stats for each ID?

Comment: Might be better to post this over at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question of mine might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181514/access-previously-stored-visitor-level-custom-variable

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is against the Google Analytics TOS, but to answer your question, once you set a Visitor Level custom variable, that is with them for the life of the cookie (24 months or deleted).  If you overwrite the variable on login, you will lose the previous value you wrote, but it should still function in the way you want, assuming you know the unique value you set to the cookie in the first place.

Comment: I don't believe it's in violation of Google's T.O.S because I'm not linking them back to any personally identifiable information. The value that they are assigned is only an incremental counter on the server, so there's no way to tell what number is what user. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right, they recently clarified that internal product IDs are ok to store in GA